# How to show one view controller in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

HI I'm using below code for Landscape Mode for only one view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return NO;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; // or Right of course
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

It is working fine But when i rotate to Portrait Then it is rotating and i'm using below code for presenting the view

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

where I'm Missing Thanks in advance

Comment: the same question asked yesterday

Comment: can i know  whether your app is made for portrait or landscape?@Bittoo

Comment: @Madhu both But one view controller in landscape

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

In your `AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldRotate;

AppDelegate.m

BOOL shouldRotate;
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
            if (self.shouldRotate)
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
            else
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
```

Now open your ViewController in which you want to apply orientations and use this code

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate setShouldRotate:YES]; // set NO to disable rotation
```

Comment: I tried as you said but it is rotate to potrait mode also